# $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function error in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrapvalidator

I'm constantly getting `$(...).bootstrapValidator` is not a function. 
In my `app.blade` I have included:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.2.1.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-ui.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-validator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.js"></script>
```

and in my `register.blade` I have a script for my bootstrap validator.

The function is valid in a regular php code, I just get this error when I try to implement it in Laravel project. Any suggestions?

Much appreciated

Comment: there might be problem with sequence of your code, you might be calling bootstrap validator function before including library.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik the libraries are included in the <head> section of the app.blade, and the bootstrap validation f-n is called at the end of the register.blade view. This is why it is confusing me

Comment: Have you checked it via view source in browser? And its good if you load JS in footer.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik yes, I checked it via view source, the libraries are loaded first

Comment: Can you show the javascript code?

Comment: How does your `app.blade` relate to `register.blade`?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. There was some intertwining with another jQuery script